# Question about ODE : does $|y|=D|x|\iff y=C x$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

In resolving ODE, I often have the following problem :

Let $$xy'-y=0.$$
Then, if $x\neq 0$ and $y\neq 0$,
$$\frac{y'}{y}=\frac{1}{x}\iff \ln|y|=\ln|x|+K, \quad K\in \mathbb R$$
and thus $|y|=D|x|$ for $D>0$ and thus $$y=\pm D |x|\iff y=M|x|,\quad M\in \mathbb R$$
because we also have that $0$ is solution. But I think that we can say more : $$y=\pm D |x|\iff y=Mx,\quad M\in \mathbb R,$$
i.e. we can take the absolute value off because $$|y|=|x|\iff y=\pm x$$
and thus if $D>0$ (as previously) we have $$|y|=D|x|\iff y=\pm D x\iff y=Mx,\quad M\in \mathbb R$$
**Q1) Am I correct ?**

In the solution my teacher always does it. The problem it's that in one equation, he didn't do it and did as following :

$$u'-\frac{8}{3x}u=0.$$
He did as :
$$\frac{u'}{u}=\frac{8}{3x}\iff \ln|u|=\frac{8}{3}\ln|x|+C\iff |u|=D|x|^{8/3}\iff u=K|x|^{8/3}$$
with $C\in \mathbb R$, $D>0$ and finally $K\in \mathbb R$.

**Q2) Why he let the absolute value ? Can't we write $u=K x^{8/3}$ ? Indeed, as before $$|u|=D|x|^{8/3}\iff u=\pm D x^{8/3}\iff u=Kx^{8/3}$$
with $D>0$ and $K\in \mathbb R$**

Answer (score 0):

It isn't true that if $|y|=D|x|$ for $D>0$ then $y=M x$ for some $M\in\mathbb{R}$. For example, when $y=|x|$ the equation $|y|=|x|$ is satisfied but we can't find a $M$ such that $y=Mx$ for all $x$. If we try to make it work for $x>0$ we find that $M=1$ whereas for $x<0$ we get $M=-1$.