# Why $x^{\frac{8}{3}}$ is defined only on $\mathbb R^+$?

Tags: real-analysis

Why $x^{\frac{8}{3}}$ is defined only on $\mathbb R^+$ ? Indeed, if $x>0$, then $$(-x)^{\frac{8}{3}}=(-x^{1/3})^8=x^{8/3}$$
and all operation are well defined...

I agree with irrational power, but in this case, it looks strange.

Indeed, $x^8$ is defined over all $\mathbb R$ and $x^{\frac{1}{3}}$ also. Therefore, the composition should also be defined over all $\mathbb R$.
[image]

Comment: What makes you think it's not defined on $\mathbb{R}_{<0}$?

Comment: @vrugtehagel: The program grapher (see my picture) !

Comment: Try Desmos instead

Comment: A graph doesn't show anything. The fact that the program only graphed it on the positive numbers just shows the program isn't very intelligent

Comment: @vrugtehagel: Indeed, but I saw this question : [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2181616/question-about-ode-does-y-dx-iff-y-c-x), and I also don't understand why in one case we they get $y=Cx$ and in the other case, they don't take off the absolute value (i.e.e they let $C|x|^{8/3}$)

Comment: Most likely, the program you used to draw the graph converted $8/3$ to floating point first. At that point, any information on whether the denominator is even or odd is lost, so it can't do the powers of negative numbers. (Actually, any non-integral floating point number is an exact representation of a fraction whose denominator is a power of $2$.)

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/940673/1508) has some discussion.

Comment: It's a question of conventions; you can define $x^{8/3}$ also for negative $x$, but you have to be careful about doing algebra with the exponents, because $x^{16/6}$ would, by the same reasons, be defined only for $x\ge0$.

Comment: @egreg: I don't agree with that. $8/3$ is _the same as_ $16/6$, so $x^{16/6}$ must equal $x^{8/3}$. See my answer to the question I linked to in the previous comment.

Comment: @TonyK If you consider them as numbers, they are obviously equal. Otherwise you couldn't justify $\frac{1}{6}+\frac{8}{3}=\frac{1}{6}+\frac{16}{6}=\frac{17}{6}$. Therefore, why should $x^{8/3}$ be different from $x^{16/6}$? But, as I said, it's a question of conventions. Provided you don't do algebra on these expressions, you can define whatever you prefer. But when your student will do $-1=(-1)^{1/3}=(-1)^{2/6}=1^{2/6}=1$, you'll know why I warn about carelessly using fractional exponents.

Comment: @egreg: There is no convention that defines $x^{8/3}$ to be different from $x^{16/6}$, because such a system would be unworkable. So either you insist that the exponent be interpreted as if it was in lowest terms, or you disallow fractional powers of negative numbers altogether. That is the choice.

Comment: @TonyK Exactly what I say: choose a convention and follow it, but be aware that others could be using a different one. I'm more concerned with $x^{1/3}=x^{2/6}$, of course.

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems here is that you assumed $\left(-x\right)^\frac 8 3=\left(-x^\frac 1 3\right)^8$, when it equals $\left(\left(-x\right)^\frac 1 3\right)^8$. This has multiple solutions. For positive non-zero $x$,

$$\left(-x\right)^\frac 8 3 = x^\frac 8 3\left(\left(-1\right)^\frac 1 3\right)^8$$

Where $\left(-1\right)^\frac 1 3$ has 3 solutions:

$$-1\\​\\0.5+\frac{i\sqrt3}2\\​\\0.5-\frac{i\sqrt3}2\\​\\$$

If you define $n^\frac 1 3$ as the *real* root, then $\left(-x\right)^\frac 8 3 = x^\frac 8 3\left(-1\right)^8=x^\frac 8 3$, which is defined over all of $\mathbb R$.

If you define $n^\frac 1 3$ as the *principal* root,

$$\begin{align}
    \left(-x\right)^\frac 8 3
      &= x^\frac 8 3\left(0.5+\frac{i\sqrt3}2\right)^8
    \\&=x^\frac 8 3\left(-0.5+\frac{i\sqrt3}2\right)
    \\&=-0.5x^\frac 8 3+\frac{ix^\frac 8 3\sqrt 3}2
\end{align}$$

which is a complex number, and the principal root is usually taken.